# Class Library, Entity Framework Code First & Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first, class-library

I am having a few issues trying to get code-first Entity Framework 6.0 to build a migration with `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types`. I still keep getting:

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.

Everywhere I look they keep talking about running:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

or similar in the `global.asax`. I need to run this in a class library which handles the data layer of my application, so there isn't a startup event.

I have put in

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Test.Startup), "Start")]
namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static void Start()
        { 
             SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

But that has not had any effect. Anyone got any other ideas?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ooh! I just had this problem last week!

Let's start by clarifying a few things. This error is caused by the lack of having an assembly to manage the Sql Server Spatial types. You can solve this issue by either:

- Installing SQL Server on the machine
- Taking a dependency on a NuGet package.

Typically, going with the NuGet package is easier, so I'm going to explain that.

The version of the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types) that you get depends on the version of Sql Server that you have running. My version of Sql Server is `11.0.6020.0`, so I installed the `11.0.2` version of the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types). This is **super important** to match the versions.

There are **three** assemblies that you'll need.

1. `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`
2. `msvcr<Version>.dll`
3. `SqlServerSpatial<Version>.dll`

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` is a *managed* assembly, while the other two are *native* assemblies.

If you install the *correct version* of the NuGet package, then all of these should be handled for you.

After you install the NuGet package, it'll open a readme, and it gives the example on how to load the native assemblies by using the `Loader` class.

Code sample:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Lastly, you'll need to override the `SqlServerTypesAssemblyName` property in the `SqlProviderServices` static class. **Note** that this is only available in a later version of EntityFramework. I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3. In my research, others were saying that this wasn't available in earlier versions.

Once again, I was using version `11.0.2` *to match my Sql Server version*, so I used the following code:

```
SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

If you're using a newer version of Sql Server, you should be able to replace the `11` with `12`, `13`, or `14` without issues.

If it's not working, here's a quick checklist:

- Ensure that `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` is referenced.
- Ensure that the *native* assemblies are copied to your bin directory under the `..\SqlServerTypes\<Platform>\` folder. There should be **two**.
- Ensure that you're setting calling the `LoadNativeAssemblies` and setting the `SqlServerTypesAssemblyName` **before** any database operations, including creating your DbContext instance.
- If your DbContext is in a separate assembly than the executing assembly, you *may* need to reference the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly. It may not be copied over via the build/reference process.